# Как сделать контекстное меню в gui python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть gui tkinter, как мне сделать что-бы при нажатии на правую кнопку мыши(или другую) открывалось контекстное меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать экземпляр класса Menu

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mainmenu = Menu(root) 
root.config(menu=mainmenu)
```

И потом добавлять  нужные команды

```
mainmenu.add_command(label='Файл')
mainmenu.add_command(label='Справка')
```

Более подробно написано [здесь](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/menu.php)

Comment: Ссылка правильная, но пример вы добавили для создания главного меню. Пример контекстного меню по той же ссылке ниже есть.